# connect a biometric sensor to my java application

Tags: java, javafx, fingerprint, biometrics

I have purchased a simple biometric fingerprint reader that is usually used for laptop security through a USB connection.
The link is

http://www.amazon.in/Morpho-MSO-1300-E2-Bio-metric-Fingerprint-Identifications/dp/B01MY159VV/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1490947570&sr=8-1&keywords=fingerprint+scanner+usb

It has not come with any software.

I am intending to create a database in `oracle` of users fingerprints so that I can identify which user swiped their fingers on it, ie, to use it for different users' authentication using fingerprints. I don't seem to be making any head or tail on how to go about that.

I would like to find out how to connect this device in my `java` application to take input from the device. Is there other kind of software to install.

Comment: if the sensor doesnt have an API how do you suppose to use it then? claim your money back!!!

Comment: But its said in the description plug and play no software installation needed

Comment: A little googling on 'morpho mso 1300 SDK' got me a few hits, it looks like they have drivers for windows and linux and also an SDK you can use to integrate it. Give it a shot, it's called 'Morphokit'.

Comment: I have searched the driver and installed   my laptop related drivers but it still doesn't recognize the device as seperate biometric sensor

Comment: I believe the SDK is written in C or C++. You will need to implement your own shared libary using this code which can then be accessed by your java application through JNI/JNA. Some basic C knowledge will be required.

Comment: I got a biometric sdk in java but it showed error no input detected

Comment: You've misunderstood what "plug & play" means.

Comment: but if we want to do the scanning part of fingerprint in java like its done by the driver

Comment: @akshitagupta did you succeed ?

Comment: I have changed the sensor to mantra 100 mfs now till will come tomorrow